# Determine source of dependency version override in Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have declared a dependency for `org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1.d91bf785-groovy-2.4`, but in runtime scope it is overridden to `1.0-groovy-2.4`.  Is there a way to figure out which dependency is overriding it?

`1.0-groovy-2.4` is not present in any gradle file locally, and it is not visible when I run `gradle dependencies` in the `shared-config` project.

Here's `gradle dependencies` from the `main-web` project:

```
testCompile
[...]
+--- project :shared-config
|    [...]
|    +--- org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1.d91bf785-groovy-2.4
[...]
runtime
[...]
+--- project :shared-config
|    [...]
|    +--- org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1.d91bf785-groovy-2.4 -> 1.0-groovy-2.4
|    |    +--- org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4 -> 1.1.d91bf785-groovy-2.4
|    |    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.1 -> 2.4.12
```

`dependencyInsight` gives some insight:

```
$ gradle dependencyInsight --dependency org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.4 --configuration runtime    
> Task :main-web:dependencyInsight
org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.4 (selected by rule)

org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1.d91bf785-groovy-2.4 -> 1.0-groovy-2.4
\--- project :shared-config
     \--- runtime
```

But the same command in the `shared-config` project doesn't yield any results:

```
No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':shared-config:runtime'
```

I have tried overriding the version without success:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1.d91bf785-groovy-2.4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are using spring boot as a parent or spring boot dependencies as a bom (dependency manager)

by default in latest spring boot versions 1.5 + `spock.version` is set to `1.0-groovy-2.4` that's why `spock-core` still have old version.

In order to fix this in gradle you need to override property `spock.version` in your gradle app. By adding `spock.version = 1.1-groovy-2.4` to `gradle.properties` file.

Visit [Spring doc for overriding dep properties](https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/Athens-SR6/reference/html/getting-started-overriding-versions.html#getting-started-overriding-versions-gradle) to find more.

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out as well, but forgot to update my answer.  I use `ext["spock.version"] = ...` myself.  Other version identifiers to look out for are in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L47